# Java not using significant CPU when rendering

Tags: java, jpanel, slowdown

So I'm writing a program in java which involves drawing lots and lots of lines, and to make it look better, I'm using antialiasing on my jPanel. When it renders with lots of lines, I get insane amounts of slow down, yet my CPU usage for java stays at ~2% usage. Is there a reason for that/a way to force it to use more CPU?
Thanks!

Comment: `I get insane amounts of slow down,` - what do you mean? The rendering doesn't just stop in the middle and do nothing. If it only takes 2% CPU, then that is all that is needed to do the rendering. If you think the painting should be faster than post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. You probably have other problems in the code not related to the rendering.

Comment: Create Threads running infinite loops with no sleep. Thats what you're wanting? More CPU usage?

Comment: Perhaps the antialiasing is being done in your graphics hardware, but you have a lousy graphics card.

Comment: camickr: I apologize for my vagueness. When I said insane amounts of slow down, I meant that the rendering itself would take longer to do with say, 1800 lines. Obviously, there's going to be a noticeable change in rendering speed from only rendering 360 to 1800, but what confused me was the slow rendering speed, but the low CPU usage. It's not so much a problem now, I was going about doing a ray-casting demo completely wrong, but now I don't need to use a number of rays large enough to cause noticeable slowdown.

Comment: Ernest: My PC is an Alienware M15x so as far as mobile graphics cards go, it's on the upper end of the spectrum. I also wasn't aware if Java renders using the GPU or CPU, but apparently its the GPU.